# thread 1: exc bad access 0 x 48

Tags: swift3, xcode8

[here is the image of the error on Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqUND.png)

when I push a button that is supposed to stop the audio, it just stops the whole app and crashes. feel free to give me some help to fix this problem.
This part of the code is where that button is hooked up to,

```
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
if audioPlayer1.isPlaying {      //error is here on this line.
        audioPlayer1.stop()
    } else {
        self.audioPlayer1.play()
}
```

here is the code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  app21
//
//  Created by Jared Evan Miller on 8/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Jared Evan Miller. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let soundFilenames = ["5","8","7","4","6","1","3","2"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
var lastAudioPlayer = 0
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// set up audio players
   for sound in soundFilenames{
        do {
            // Try to do somerhing
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")!);
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {

            // Catch the error that is thrown
            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())


        }
               }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped

    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()

}

@IBAction func buttonTapped2(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()

}
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if audioPlayer1.isPlaying {      //error is here on this line.
        audioPlayer1.stop()
    } else {
        self.audioPlayer1.play()
}
}
}
```

how do I fix this?
thanks for your help!!!!!

Comment: You are creating `audioPlayer1` with the default initializer `()` but there is no `data` nor `contentsOfURL` to be played. So what's the purpose of `audioPlayer1` (variable names with appended index numbers could be confusing) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below line :

```
let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
```

It should be like below. Because you already initialized audioPlayer.

```
audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
```

Find the below code :

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if audioPlayer.isPlaying { //Here you are trying on audioPlayer1 and you are not initialized this anywhere
        audioPlayer.stop()
    } else {
        self.audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```